# Mysql get count users in group

Tags: mysql

I have a question which I cant really work out.  I have 1 table with 2 2 columns, userid and groupid

entries:

- user1: group1
- user1: group2
- user1: group3
- user2: group1
- user2: group2
- user3: group1

Now I want to make a Sql query that which gives the following data:

there are 3 people that are a member of 1 group

there are 2 people that are a member of 2 groups

there is 1 person that is a member of 3 groups.

Comment: 'there are 3 people that are a member of 1 group' not so only user3 is a member of only 1 group (user1 is a member of 3 groups and user2 is a member of 2 groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to precompute the counts, and then a simple aggregation will do:

```
select c, count(*)
from (
  select count(distinct g) as c from t group by u
) x 
group by c
```

Assumes the table is `t`, with columns `u` and `g`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*), groupname-attribute 
 from tablename 
group by groupname-attribute;
```

This query will show you the count of each group in a tabular format.

Comment: But that's not the question.